# how can I create a MySQL account using terminal

Tags: command-line, mysql

I have tried using the root,  but I receive errors.

```
 mysql -u root 
  File "<ipython-input-6-c07024211ca7>", line 1
    mysql -u root
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include examples of specific commands you have tried, and the error messages that result - as it stands, it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: wait this is from a piece of code? or command line? Me confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql -u root File ""
```

Is not valid.

I would expect this from the bash prompt:

```
mysql -u root -p < file.sql
```

- where file.sql contains valid SQL and it will be executed on the database noted in file.sql. Otherwise supply a database after "-p " and before the "<".
- and -p will prompt for the password for root.